# Blade PHP Variable undefined in Local Laravel Project but not Production?

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework, laravel-blade

I have a very weird error in my Laravel project. Some code in my Blade view file runs perfectly on the server but fails on my local project VM.

The simple code is:

```
<?$class = 'abc';?>
<p><?=$class?></p> /* My local project fails here */
```

On my local Laravel project I get the error:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: class

Why the difference? I'm really curious to know why this would work on the server but fail locally.

Server Setup:

- CentOS 6.8 VPS
- Laravel Version `Laravel Framework version 5.2.45`
- PHP Version `PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2017 08:42:18)`
- `Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`

Local Setup:

- Windows 10
- Homestead VM
- Laravel Version `Laravel Framework version 5.2.45`
- PHP Version `PHP 5.6.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)`
- `Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
  with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
  with blackfire v1.6.0, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.`

**Edit:** After Steve's advice. If I change the code to the below it works. Whats going on?

```
<?php $class = 'abc';?>
<p><?=$class?></p
```

Comment: `<?$class = 'abc';?>` could be the issue, `<?` is a short open tag, which are not enabled by default (not to be confused with `<?=` which is a short echo tag, and is enabled by default) - try <?php $class='abc';?> to test. Or its a cache / compile issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/undefined-variable-error

Comment: @Steve yes if I change it to `<?php $class=...` it works on my local project. Whats going on? And how can I setup my local PHP to allow the short open tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand my comment into an answer, `<?$class = 'abc';?>` could be the issue, `<?` is a short open tag, which are not enabled by default (not to be confused with `<?=` which is a short echo tag, and is enabled by default).

If this is the case, then you should edit your php.ini with:

`short_open_tag = On`

to match your live environment, or replace all instances of `<?` (thats including the trailing space so you dont catch the perfectly valid `<?=`) with `<?php` throughout the project.

generally short open tags are disabled because they can cause issues reading xml, so i would personally opt for the second option.

Either way be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

May be you cannot use short tag `<?` on your local environment. Check `short_open_tag` value in your local `php.ini` file.

From documentation: PHP also allows for short open tag

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Or just use

```
<?php $class = 'abc'; ?>
```

instead of

```
<?$ $class = 'abc'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally I discovered the issue after half day of work. check the component folder should start with uppercase!